# Gallery database design question regarding permissions/visibility

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a gallery. I want users to be able to choose who can view their photos by group or individual. I figure I should have a table `can_see` with two columns `(user_id, photo_id)`. This should work for individuals, but it won't work if I toss `group_id`s in there too. I'm thinking the best approach might be just to add each individual in the selected group to that table when a group is chosen, rather than its `group_id`. This however creates more entries in the table to sift through later. Is this still the best approach?

---

Here's what I have in mind:

```
users: id, username, ...
photos: id, album_id, ...
albums: id, user_id (owns all photos in album), ....
can_see: user_id, photo_id
groups: id, user_id(owner), name
member_of: user_id, group_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to eliminate the amount of entries to search, I would go for the following approach.

```
User Table - UserID, UserName
Group Table - GroupID, GroupName
User Group Table - GroupID, UserID
Photo Table - PhotoID, UserID
```

If you would like to access photos for a specific user, you would get the User ID from user table and do a lookup by that ID on the photo table.

If you would like to access photos for a group, you would get the UserIDs from User Group table and do a lookup of those IDs on the photo table.

***Detailed comment

> ok let me spell it out for you...There
>   are couple of actions here to be
>   performed by a photo owner or atleast
>   that is my understanding.
>   1. Photo owner may grant viwership access to a single user. 
>   This will create a new record in the user table
>   for a new user. For existing users it
>   won't. This will also create a new
>   record in the photo table with the
>   existing or newly created user ID.
>   2. Photo owner may grant viewership access to a group of users. 
>   This action will create a new record in the
>   group table for a new group and for
>   existing group it won't. Any new users
>   in the group will require new record
>   additions to the user table.
>   Eventually, photo table will be
>   updated with as many records as there
>   are users in the group.
>
> Now to access the photos...There are
>   multiple cases
>
> 1. A single user who does not belong to any group can request access to the
>      photo.
> 2. A single user who is part of some group can request access to the photo.
>
> In eiher of these cases, I am assuming
>   the input from the application will
>   have just the user name & the photo to
>   access (This should actually be the
>   album. Since you amended your question
>   I am not sure if this is still the
>   case). In which case, you will do a
>   lookup in the user table to get the
>   user ID for the user name and will do
>   another lookup in the photo table to
>   see if this user ID is granted access
>   to the requested photo or not (by
>   checking if the record exists or not).
>
> So the next question is...why do we
>   need group & user-group tables? This
>   is required for the photo owner to
>   easily grant and revoke access
>   privileges from the UI. With these
>   table it is easy to build an UI to
>   show the photo owner what groups were
>   created and the members of each group.
>
> There are certain items missing from
>   the question...For instance, how does
>   one request for viewing access? What
>   information will provided as input to
>   the application? All the comments and
>   answer updates from me are based on lot
>   of assumptions. So now we know why
>   requirements should be clearly spelled
>   out;-)

Comment: I think either you or I have a misunderstanding.

We're not searching for photos, we trying to determine who has permission to see the photo. How would you do that with this setup?

I'm not even sure how your "user group table" works. If I have 5 users that are all part of the same group, what happens? The group name is repeated 5 times? That's just bad design.

I'll ammend my question with my setup...

Comment: Agreed. My earlier design for user group table with repeated group name is not a good design as you rightly pointed out. I have modified the design a little bit to reflect my actual thought. By searching I actually meant accessing.

Comment: I still don't get it. You make it sound like either an individual user *owns* the photo, or the entire *owns* the photo. What if User A uploads Photo B, and then along comes User C who wants to see Photo B. How do we check if he has permission to do so? According to you we pull up his UserID from the User Table, and then check the Photo Table... but the Photo Table just describes who owns it. You're still missing a visibility table.

Comment: According to my design, it is the photo owner who will provide access permissions for other users or groups to view the photos. In your example that would be user A granting viewership to User C to view his photo B. This should in turn create an entry in the user table and in the photo table. With this User B should be able to view User A's photo B.

Comment: Oh... your photo table is my can_see table then? I thought it was storing the photo info too. Why is it creating an entry in both the user table and the photo table? And the group thing still doesn't make any sense. "access photos for a group" just isn't right. It's "if a member of a group requests to see a photo"... why are we checking multiple UserIDs against the photo table? We only want to check if one specific user can or can't see it? You don't have to bother responding to this, we just don't seem to be seeing eye-to-eye.

Comment: I have added a detailed comment to my answer since the comments section is too small.

Comment: So... each user within a group that is given permission will eventually be added to the Photo Table? If so, your solution is identical to mine, and has the same faults that it does not reduce the number of entries in the Photo Table, AND if the group members are modified after a group has been given permissions, how do we know which users to remove or add to the Photo Table?

Comment: Well adding a group ID column to the photo table will allow for removing members from a group. However, if you absolutely need to reduce the number of entries, you can just go with one ID column in the photo table that will hold both group ID and User ID. However, you need to make sure the IDs have some unique prefixes like User and Group before them. For instance User_100, User_101...Group_100, Group_101...etc. This should work correctly for all your cases. Adding & removing group members should be much easier with this approach.

Comment: I thought about that too, but then it makes it harder to query... oh well. +1 for effort :)

Comment: Ok I think I found the solution that you are looking for. How about making the photo table have three fields - photo ID, ID and ID Type. ID field can have either the user ID or the group ID. However, it is the ID type field that will tell you what type of ID it is whether a user or a group id. You can designate numbers like 0 to represent user & 1 to represent group IDs or you could use characters like 'U' and 'G'. This will reduce the number of entries & will work well with all the scenarios.

Comment: Well, sure, I thought about that too, but now that we have two fields, why not just store the IDs directly in those fields? That way I don't have to query it, find out what it is, and then based on that do another query? Instead I can say "hey, is this group allowed to view this?" instead of "hey, is this a group entry, and if so, is this group allowed to view it?"

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I thought of, we can ammend the `can_see` table to include a `group_id` column, then to check if a user can see a photo:

```
SELECT 1 FROM can_see WHERE user_id=USERID AND photo_id=PHOTOID
```

or

```
SELECT 1 FROM can_see JOIN member_of ON can_see.group_id = member_of.group_id WHERE member_of.user_id=USERID AND can_see.photo_id=PHOTOID
```

It's extra column which might often be `null`, and it means we have to do 2 queries instead of 1 to check permissions, but it keeps the `can_see` table a bit smaller, and it means you can modify the group after permissions are set.