# jsp code for verify login

Tags: jsp

I need to do a login page which can verify 3 different types of user, which are student, lecturer and admin by using only 1 login form.
I have 3 table which are student -> metric, stu_name, stu_pass
                         lecturer -> s_code, lec_name, lec_pass
                         admin -> id, ad_name, ad_pass
I don't know how to code it.Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set the structure of your database that can check what type of user they are. You can combine your three table into one then add the user types.

```
Table: user 
userId   +    password    +   name       +   userType
10001    |    123456      |   Admin      |   STUDENT
10002    |    123456      |   LecturerA  |   LECTURER
10003    |    123456      |   StudentA   |   STUDENT
```

Now on your login form it is ok just to have a text input for userId and password.

The key here is to get the user type during validation. Of course you need to include this in your query.

Sample (? is the value from your input fields)

```
SELECT name, userType FROM user WHERE userId = ? AND password = ?;
```

Now for the page I'll just make a pseudo-code and it's up to you how you'll manage it. Because I don't know how will you display the page.

Pseudo-codes

```
If userType equal to null //This means invalid userId and password
    redirect to login and prompt user for invalid user and password
Else If userType equal to ADMIN
    Show the admin page
Else If userType equal to LECTURER
    Show the lecturer page
Else If userType equal to STUDENT
    Show the user page
```

There are a lot of things to work. But you can use this as a starting point and then maximize it for your own development needs.

**UPDATED:**

Before doing the coding phase in your application be sure you have designed it properly. Specially in your case that you need different user type that use different module. You must know a good way of handling the user permission in your module.

Examples:

- [@SO Best Practice for Designing User Roles and Permission System ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333620/best-practice-for-designing-user-roles-and-permission-system)
- [@SO Gallery database design question regarding permissions/visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973416/gallery-database-design-question-regarding-permissions-visibility)

Sample Structure

```
Table: user
userId  +  password   +   name
10001   |  123456     |   Admin
10002   |  123456     |   LecturerA
10003   |  123456     |   StudentA

Table: module
moduleCode   +   moduleName
MC0001       |   ADMIN     
MC0002       |   LECTURER
MC0003       |   STUDENT

Table: usermodule
uniqueId    +   userId   +   moduleCode
1           |   10001    |   MC0001
2           |   10001    |   MC0002
3           |   10002    |   MC0003
4           |   10003    |   MC0004
```

And the query something like

```
SELECT 
      m.moduleName
   FROM user u 
  INNER JOIN usermodule um 
     ON u.userId = um.userId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN module m
     ON um.moduleCode = m.moduleCode
  WHERE u.userId = ? AND password = SHA1(?)
```

Note the query is not tested but it will be something like that. Here you will have a list of module with permission.

In real business you will need more table than this.

Comment: If without combine the table and i want to verify through their id means for example student metric is all int value eg:149277, for lecturer, s_code will start with Axxxx eg:A0001 while for admin he/ she can also be the lecturer. How to write the query for it?

Comment: First of all you need to have a good design of schema. But for your question if the table is not combine I guess it will be difficult. Because you don't know which table to use, in this case you can use a select box as Nathanphan suggested. But did you saw many login page like this? If you really want to use 3 tables first you need a user table which store the userId and table name for which type they are. Then you will use the table name for your next query and also will use this as the userType as I explain in my pseudo-codes. Then for the admin you need column to identify if can lecture.

Answer (score 1):

use this code in html page.

```
  <form method="post" id="loginform" name="form" action="cStaffLogin">

        <select name="UserRole" style="width:250px;">

        <option id="#">Select Role</option>
        <option id="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
        <option id="LECTURER"> LECTURER</option>
        <option id="STUDENT"> STUDENT</option>

        </select>
    </form>
```

### cStaffLogin

use this code in Servlet

```
String strUserRole = request.getParameter("UserRole");

if(strUserRole.equals("ADMIN"))
{
RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj =request.getRequestDispatcher("/Admin.jsp");
RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
}

if(strUserRole.equals("LECTURER"))
{
RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj =request.getRequestDispatcher("/Lecturer.jsp");
RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
}

if(strUserRole.equals("STUDENT"))
{
RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj =request.getRequestDispatcher("/Student.jsp");
RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
}
```

SIMPLEST SOLUTION IS GIVEN ABOVE.....

Answer (score 0):

It is too easy. You create a drop down box which contains 3 user types : student, admin, lecture.

if you are using servlet as contrller, when the request is sent to the controller, check if the value of drop down box is student, admin, or lecturer. Then do what you want to validate with each type of user.

Have a nie day

Comment: If i not doin the drop down list how can i verify through their id? Let say the student metric is int eg: 123456, lecturer s_code is start with Axxxx eg: A0001, while for admin it may be can be a lecturer also.

Comment: yes if you want to, you can use substring to get the prefix, then compare to what want

Comment: I suggest you should use drop down box, it is  more professional,stable,and expandable (in case you want more user type).